# Unset key binding to tmm in aquamacs

Tags: key-bindings, aquamacs

I use aquamacs on mac and the latest version apparently maps `` M-` ``  and `M-'` to tmm functions (which I don't use and don't care to). This is annoying since these are used for accented letters, in all mac softwares and I normally use it in aquamacs for LaTeX. How can I unset these bindings globally in aquamacs ?

Comment: I don't really know how to properly type the code blocks when it includes the backquote. Any hint would be useful to improve the presentation of my question.

Comment: [You use more than one backquote](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code). This works *almost* all the time, except for the cases where the "real" backquote is at the beginning or end of the string (as in this case). I cheat in those cases and add an extra space before or after the "real" backquote to separate it from the "quoting" backquotes. It is possible that a zero-width space might be used instead to make it look better, but I can never remember how to get a zero-width space from my keyboard - it doesn't help that I need it once in a blue moon, so I have no muscle memory...

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found a working solution to my problem. I added

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-`"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-\'"))
```

to the file:

`Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el`

and I can type accents in the usual way.

Comment: After some time working with that, I realize that this does the trick but aquamacs complains with ``Invalid read syntax: ")"``. The trouble is that the rest of the startup file does not appear to be executed then.

Comment: Corrected the answer to remove the error ``Invalid read syntax: ")"``.